# No RenderWindow class in SFML?

Tags: sfml

In their official tutorials it is said that to draw graphics on screen, i have to use RenderWindow instead of Window. But when i write sf:: RenderWindow window, error pops up saying that there is no RenderWindow in sf::  . I  copy-pasted the code but it still does not works. What could possibly be the  reason behind this ?

Comment: `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` ?

Comment: @Alayric yes. I was using   **#include <SFML/Window.hpp>**   instead of   **#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>**,   and that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sf::Window is part of the SFML Window module but sf::RenderWindow is part of the SFML Graphics module. Hence you have to include SFML/Graphics.hpp in order to use it.